# My code about creating label dynamically in a loop don't work, only one appear

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controls

I'm creating an application, where for each Char in a txt file (*where some text is written*), a label containing one char letter from the txt is created and written. 
In the txt file, "Hello" is written, and only the **H** appear

Here's my actual code :

```
string test = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"../../../../../Texte/Test.txt");
int x = 20;
int y = 20;
int i = 10;

foreach (char ch in test) {
    Label newlabel = new Label();
    newlabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x + i, y);
    newlabel.Text = ch.ToString();
    panel1.Controls.Add(newlabel);
    i += 15;
}
```

Comment: Before the loop, what is the value of `panel1.Controls.Count`? What about after the loop? _After means **outside** of the loop, not **inside** of the loop._

Comment: Change position for each label, i think they are placed in the same location

Comment: Have you tried setting to a small size, and setting `AutoSize` to `true` like in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.autosize?view=netframework-4.7.2 ?

Comment: Just make 15 bigger this should work like 151

Comment: I'd just use a GroupBox instead of a panel, it'll work first time.

Comment: Taking a step back, why do you want multiple labels at all? Why not use a single label that contains **the entire string**?

Comment: @mjwills Thanks you ! It worked ! Setting the autosize and Anil you were right too, for making 15 bigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set AutoSize property of your label to TRUE. Without setting this property the first label covers the rest, so you can see only the first one. Try the following:

```
foreach (char ch in test) {
    Label newlabel = new Label();
    newlabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x + i, y);
    newlabel.Text = ch.ToString();
    newlabel.AutoSize = true; 
    panel1.Controls.Add(newlabel);
    i += 15;
}
```